# Bootstrap Ajax Tabs Not Preloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap Tabs and loading them with Jquery in a Asp.net MVC5 web app. But Tab 1 (30days) is not loading on page load. I have rechecked the code many times but couldn't find out the issue. Can you guys please take a look on this where I am doing wrong. Thanks

**HTML**

```
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Hot Stories</h3>
                <span class="pull-right">
                    <!-- Tabs -->
                    <ul class="nav panel-tabs" id="HotStoriesTabs">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#30Day" data-toggle="tab" data-url="/HotStories30Days">30 days</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#14Day" data-toggle="tab" data-url="/HotStories14Days">14 days</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#7Day" data-toggle="tab" data-url="/HotStories7Days">7 days</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="30Day"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-2x fa-pulse"></i></div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="14Day"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-2x fa-pulse"></i></div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="7Day"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-2x fa-pulse"></i></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#HotStoriesTabs a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr("data-url");
        var href = this.hash;
        var pane = $(this);
        $(href).load(url, function (result) {
            pane.tab('show');
        });
    });

    // tab to load on page load
    $('#30Day').load($('.active a').attr("data-url"), function (result) {
        $('.active a').tab('show');
    });
    });
```

Comment: There is no element with id 30Day

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: Please check again. `<div class="tab-pane active" id="30Day">` in `panel-body`

Comment: sorry did'nt saw that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is the first anchor tag which is for 30 Days, you can use `first()` function to get first tag after registering click event and using `click()` or `trigger('click')`  to call click on it programmatically :

```
 $('#HotStoriesTabs a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("data-url");
    var href = this.hash;
    var pane = $(this);
    $(href).load(url, function (result) {
        pane.tab('show');
    });
}).first().click();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please take look on this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aadi1295/tapo7t3u/2/), my code working fine and first tab is loading on pageload, but not sure why it isn't working in my mvc project.

Comment: your solution working fine btw in my mvc project, but according to the documentation my code should also work and it's actually working fine in jsFiddle I shared. Can you point out the issue If I am doing something wrong. Thanks for the answer btw.

Comment: have you checked using dev tools console for some js or jquery error?